# How to know which SDHC cards are optimized for short random accesses?

Tags: raspberry-pi, sdhc

A Raspberry Pi Engineer wrote [here](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=81743#p655952) the following

> Class 10 are optimised for long sequential bursts of data. But the Raspi on average produces short random accesses. So a card optimised for the latter will work faster than one optimised for the former. I suspect that modern class 10 are actually fairly good at random access now as well though.

I'm currently searching for a card for my Raspberry Pi 2. How do I know which card is optimized for short random accesses?

Comment: Actual high speed sd cards Are faster at Both.  Actual high speed, meaning there are cards with big numbers , and cards that test out well when you get them home.  So generally just get good real cards with good real speed, and the small random will take care of itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can refer to benchmarks comparing random read/write performance, particularly using small transfer sizes.

This benchmark done at Tom's Hardware compares random reads/writes of 4KB operations amongst several SD cards, which I believe is just what you're looking for: http://www.tomshardware.com/charts/sd-cards-2014/benchmarks,168.html